# futurama bash scheme

Tags: macos, bash, colors

Is there a color scheme for the BASH shell that matches the blackboard colors on futurama?
[image]

(If it matters, I'm on OSX.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the colors in Terminal's *Preferences*. The profiles, including color settings, are on the second tab there.

Use the color picker to get the colors off the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in mac os x, using terminal, go to Terminal -> Preferences. Select the "Settings" Tab from the top bar of the newly shown screen.  Select the settings you would like to change from the menu on the left of the window, or hit "+" to create new settings.  Once you have selected the shell settings you would like to edit, click "Text" under the Text tab to change the color of the text.  Select the "Window Tab" to change the background text.

Answer (score 0):

Set your terminal forground to the RGB color **30, 214, 123**

Set your terminal background to the RGB color **17, 145, 78**