# Syntax highlighting in Terminal Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion, terminal.app, syntax-highlighting

How can I highlight different parts in the Mac OS X Terminal app? For example a different color for input and output? Are the pre-defined color themes I can activate/download?

Comment: you can use some of the themes from http://www.toddwerth.com/ as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A great way to get basic syntax highlighting on your console is to install [fishfish](https://fishshell.com/). It offers basic syntax highlighting and [much more](http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/index.html).

Here is a screenshot of how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/232828/22317) explains how to configure the colors used by your Terminal profiles (e.g. [a Futurama based color scheme](https://superuser.com/a/266822/22317)) and how to enable color output for selected commands.

You can easily adapt [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/204014/22317) to make only your command input colored by applying [what is explained in this post's section *Colors*](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/21/customizing-your-bash-command-prompt/) instead of making text bold.